# designing a speed bump to enforce a certain speed limit

Tags: classical-mechanics

How would you design a speed bump to enforce a certain speed limit for standard cars? What would you change in the design of a car to let it go faster over speed bumps?

Comment: Aside:  A university at which I once worked installed metal triangular speed bumps on campus.  They were jarring if you rolled over them.   I accidentally discovered that if I hit them at a speed *greater than* some speed ... around 30 mph ... you could breeze over them almost as if they weren't even there.

Comment: This might be useful : [Magic Speed to Drive Over a Speed Bump](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136102)

Answer (score 1):

To go over speed bumps without the car jarring, you'd want to remove your shock absorbers.  That's not a good solution for general driving, of course.  Going
rapidly enough over speed bumps may activate the pressure relief valves in your
shocks, so at some speed the bumps are less of a jolt, BUT the stresses on your car's tires are very high (that's why the shocks have relief valves) and
it isn't a good practice.

At low speed, the car moves up and down by 4 inches for a 4 inch bump.
At moderate speed, the wheels move up and down by 4 inches, and the car by 6
inches (shocks and spring compression result in overshoot).
At high speed, the wheels move up and down by 4 inches, and the car by 1 inch,
and as long as the pressure relief in the shocks works well, the tires
don't burst from the strain.

To tune the speed bumps, design so the overshoot occurs slightly above the 
targeted speed.   A tentative driver will note things getting worse, and slow.

Comment: What would you change about the design of the speed bump? Height or profile?

Comment: Profile change is rich with possibilities (up to a full washboard road); height change is more limited, unless you are OK with scraping lots of lowriders.

Answer (score 0):

A longer wheel base would help the car go over the bump with less impact to the vehicle. Picture a fulcrum under the middle of the vehicle. Now extend an imaginary beam on that fulcrum. Picture a very short beam and a very long beam. Easy to see that the longer the beam results in less movement to the vehicle.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer, given the broad nature of the question.